# How to get the result from other Promise with async await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, serverless-framework

Im try working with serverless framework, right now im have 2 files:

1. server.js => handle connection to monggoDB
2. handler.js => this will handle function from serverless framework to lambda

I want to get the result from server.js first, before running the next step.

I'm trying to use await dan save the result to a variable, 
the process in handler.js will run synchronous but the startServer() result is undefined

```
// server.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbHost = require('../config/keys').mongoURI;

module.exports = async () => {
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

  return await mongoose
    .connect(
      dbHost,
      { useNewUrlParser: true }
    )
    .then(res => {
      console.log('MongoDB Connected', res);
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      console.error('MongoDB Not Connected');
      return err;
    });
};

// handler.js
const startServer = require('./db/server');
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  let tryConnect = await startServer();
  console.log('server is running', tryConnect);
  return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(tryConnect) };
};
```

how to get the result from await properly from nested async-await?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just return the value you get after `await`:

```
try {
    const res = await mongoose.connect(dbHost, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    console.log('MongoDB Connected', res);
    return res;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error('MongoDB Not Connected');
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of callback function on `mongoose.connect` if you are using `await`. Callback function is use for `Promise` not for `await`, use `try/catch` in `async/await`.

```js
// server.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbHost = require('../config/keys').mongoURI;

module.exports = async () => {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

    return await mongoose
        .connect(
            dbHost, {
                useNewUrlParser: true
            }
        );
};

// handler.js
const startServer = require('./db/server');
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
    let tryConnect = {};
    try {
        tryConnect = await startServer();
        console.log('MongoDB Connected', tryConnect);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.error('MongoDB Not Connected');
    }
    console.log('server is running', tryConnect);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(tryConnect)
    };
};
```